# dhclient logs flooded with useless information

Tags: debian, logs, dhclient

I am using `dhclient` on Debian (`isc-dhcp-client`, `isc-dhcp-common`).

The logs that `dhclient` is logging are flooded with copyright information and other useless stuff ("please consult README", "please visit http://...")

This is how simple `dhcp` session looks like:

```
dhclient:  Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
dhclient:  Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
dhclient:  All rights reserved.
dhclient:  For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
dhclient:  
dhclient:  Listening on LPF/wlan0/aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
dhclient:  Sending on   LPF/wlan0/aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
dhclient:  Sending on   Socket/fallback
dhclient:  DHCPRELEASE on wlan0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67
dhclient:  send_packet: Network is unreachable
dhclient:  send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
dhclient:  Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
dhclient:  Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
dhclient:  All rights reserved.
dhclient:  For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
dhclient:  
dhclient:  Listening on LPF/wlan0/aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
dhclient:  Sending on   LPF/wlan0/aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
dhclient:  Sending on   Socket/fallback
dhclient:  DHCPRELEASE on wlan0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67
dhclient:  send_packet: Network is unreachable
dhclient:  send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
dhclient:  Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
dhclient:  Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
dhclient:  All rights reserved.
dhclient:  For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
dhclient:  
dhclient:  Listening on LPF/wlan0/aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
dhclient:  Sending on   LPF/wlan0/aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
dhclient:  Sending on   Socket/fallback
dhclient:  DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
dhclient:  DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
dhclient:  DHCPOFFER from 192.168.0.1
dhclient:  DHCPACK from 192.168.0.1
dhclient:  bound to 192.168.0.16 -- renewal in 36865 seconds.
```

The important information is mixed with garbage. This is an issue for me because I am forwarding important logs (including `dhclient`), and having them displayed in the background. And since `dhclient` often renews the lease, the log can get quite long pretty quickly. I then have to scroll up to see other logs.

Is it possible to hide the garbage, and only keep the relevant information?